# Prove that $A$ is reflection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, jordan-normal-form

Prove that if $A^2=I$ and $A$ isn't scalar operator (Operator $A$ is called scalar if $Ax=\lambda x$) then $A$ is reflection operator. I have no clue how to do this problem. The only hint my teacher gave me is the fact that $A_J^2=I$ ($A_J$ is Jordan form of A)

Comment: So make a list of the possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$.

Comment: What is the definition used for reflection operator?

Comment: standart defenition like $R(x_1+x_2)=x_1-x_2$ i think, there is no specific about it

Comment: You’re going to need a more precise definition of a reflection operator than that to make any headway.

Comment: A the begining of the chapter there is definition $R: V\rightarrow V$ is defined as $R(x)=x_1-x_2$ is called reflection operator and reflect V over $L_1$ parallel $L_2$. That's the definition

Comment: That's literally just one single reflection. What about all the infinitely many other reflections? Perhaps you mean $R$ is a reflection if it is equivalent to that *in some choice of coordinates* (i.e. up to similarity). Plus, that example is only a 2D example, so what about every other dimension? And you mention "the chapter" but never said what text you're using. Note there are *improper reflections* $A$ which are not reflections and nonetheless are orthogonal and $A^2=I$. Not to mention the non-orthogonal $A$ for which $A^2=I$, like $A=[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&\lambda\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the definition for reflection operator on V is:

For $U,W\subseteq V$ s.t. $U+W=V$ and $U\cap W=\left\{ 0\right\} $

($\iff U\oplus W=V$)

Then $\forall v\in V:v=u+w$ while $u\in U,w\in W$

If $f:V\rightarrow V$, $f\left(v\right)=f\left(u+w\right)=u-w$,
then $f$ is a reflection operator.

The proof:

Let $U=\ker\left(f-\text{Id}\right),\,W=\ker\left(f+\text{Id}\right).$

If $v\in U\cap W$ then $f\left(v\right)-v=0=f\left(v\right)+v\Rightarrow v=0\Rightarrow U\cap W=\left\{ 0\right\} .$

Now we should prove $V=U+W:$

For $v\in V$, let $u=\frac{v+f\left(v\right)}{2}$ and $w=\frac{v-f\left(v\right)}{2}.$
Then $u+w=\frac{v+f\left(v\right)}{2}+\frac{v-f\left(v\right)}{2}=v.$

Additionaly, $f\left(u\right)=f\left(\frac{v+f\left(v\right)}{2}\right)=\frac{f\left(v\right)+f\left(f\left(v\right)\right)}{2}=\frac{f\left(v\right)+v}{2}=u\Rightarrow u\in U.$

And $f\left(w\right)=f\left(\frac{v-f\left(v\right)}{2}\right)=\frac{f\left(v\right)-f\left(f\left(v\right)\right)}{2}=\frac{f\left(v\right)-v}{2}=w\Rightarrow w\in W$.

(Using $f^{2}=\text{Id}$)

Hence, $U\oplus W=V$. Now, for all $v\in V$, $v=u+w$.

Finally, $f\left(v\right)=f\left(u+w\right)=f\left(u\right)+f\left(w\right)=u-w$,
i.e. $f$ is a reflection operator.

(Translated from my school's solutions)